# How to simulate real onchange for an element?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, greasemonkey

I have a **select element** that has its `onchange` event handled by a jQuery event listener,
and its `onchange` attribute is empty.

Triggering the `onchange` event by this method

```
document.getElementById("element_name").onchange();
```

is not working.

I want a solution to simulate a real full `onchange` event on that element.

Comment: -1 You have two answers that have jsFiddle proofs. I should have known better than to answer a 30% user. :(

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var element = document.getElementById("element_name");

if ('fireEvent' in element)
    element.fireEvent("onchange");
else {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Proof:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/xG7HB/

Answer (score 3):

How about...

```
$('#element_id').trigger('change');
```

... or just...

```
$('#element_id').change();
```

? Added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjR9P/) illustrating this.

Or do you need a jQuery-less solution?

Comment: Listen, no offence, but "it's not working" without any details is the least desirable response to _any_ answer - even a completely rubbish one. Wouldn't you give some details of your problem then?

Comment: Check the jsfiddle I've added. What's different in your case?

Comment: I'am making some kind of form automation using greasemonkey and firefox.
I've to select an option from a select box then that select box would fire the onchange event to do some functions.

The problem is after I choose the select option I want, it didn't fire the onchange event so I've to fire it.

Comment: The jsfiddle is working nice But That code is not working for me,
Thanks for your help anyway